# Property 'resetFilterValues' does not exist on type 'IFilterComp'

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to reset the filters after new data is being loaded to resolve the 'select all' issue but i get the below error when using resetFilterValues() function. Not sure what could be the issue. I have been seeing the documents and it looks like the function is correct but when i go to the definition of IFilterComp there is no function "resetFilterValues()"

"error TS2339: Property 'resetFilterValues' does not exist on type 'IFilterComp'."

I am using the latest version of ag-grid 21.1.0 and angular framework.

```
  var columns = this.gridOptions.columnApi.getAllColumns();
  columns.forEach(col => {
    var filter = self.gridOptions.api.getFilterInstance(col.getColId());
    if (filter.isFilterActive()) {
      var filterModel = filter.getModel();
      filter.resetFilterValues();
      filter.setModel(filterModel);
    }
    else {
      filter.resetFilterValues();
    }
  });
```

plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/yb8tHVIJpz6MVytS3Vb8?p=preview

Please check in the console log after clicking "Reset Filter" button. I am using gridOptions api call because all the components/functions/api are tied to gridOptions.

Answer (score 1):

Th reason this line throws an error is because resetFilterValues() is a set filter api as described [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-set/#set-filter-api) and it won't work for filters of other types.

The other way of resetting all filters would be to use this api function as shown in [example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-api/#reset-all-filters)

```
clearFilters() {
        this.gridApi.setFilterModel(null);
        this.gridApi.onFilterChanged(); 
}
```